# Is there any way to continue with tests in postman even if any one assert fails?

Tags: postman, assert

In a Postman `GET` request, I have used multiple assertions.  However, if any assertion fails, Postman will stops its execution then and there and will throw an error.

Is there any way to prevent this and continue with other assertions even if any one among them fails?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend you add a [mcve] to your question. Write a toy application that highlight your need. You can [edit] your question to improve it. This makes it easier for others to answer your question and avoids misunderstandings.

Comment: I've edited your question for capitalization and grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Postman has an open Feature Request on this
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4341

However, you can use command line app [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) using the *--bail* option available with it.